# host.OnAppDisposing Intermittently Invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, owin

When one wishes to dispose of `IDisposable` objects with OWIN, it was been widely recommended to use the `CancellationToken` from the host, should it be available, like so:

```
var context = new OwinContext(builder.Properties);

var token = context.Get<CancellationToken>("host.OnAppDisposing");

if (token != CancellationToken.None)
{
    token.Register(() =>
    {
      disposable.Dispose();
    });
}
```

I've registered some 12 objects for disposal with the above code inside of a `foreach` and I've found that some number of these will be called throughout the day leaving me with some resources MIA while the others remain as if nothing had happened.

Unfortunately, the documentation for both `host.OnAppDisposing` and the `CancellationToken` itself has offered me little information. There is no mention of lifecycle on the former and the latter has no mention regarding limits to `Register`.

Is there a consistent and well-documented way to handle resource disposal in a long-running ASP.NET application running on IIS?

Comment: We recycle application pools in IIS every 29 hours by default. The Aspnet_wp.exe process will keep going until you end the task, restart IIS, or restart the computer. You can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/high-memory-level

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that hosting long-living resources in an ASP.NET is something of an anti-pattern. While I cannot find documentation supporting either direction, I've found lots of chatter indicating this to be so.

I've since moved the long-living objects into a Windows Service which has been humming along for several weeks now without a hiccup.